# Click Dynamic button with Selenium (Pinterest/TailwindApp)

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the scheduling of pinning items to Pinterest using Tailwindapp.com.  I am using a console app in .NET (C#) with Selenium Chromedriver.  I start up the browser and enable the tailwind extension and login to tailwind.  Then I go to the site I am trying to pin images from, get to the product page, search for the button and attempt to click it.  That's where it falls apart.  The 'Schedule' button in Tailwind appears over all images on the page *as you hover*.  When I do an XPath search, it only returns a single button for the whole page (the console line below shows 1).

```
public static void ClickScheduleButton(IWebDriver driver) {
        // get all the buttons and then use the first one
        IList<IWebElement> buttons = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='tw_schedule_btn']"));
        Console.WriteLine("Number of items found: " + buttons.Count());
        IWebElement scheduleButton = buttons.ElementAt(0);

        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.MoveToElement(scheduleButton).Click().Perform();
    }
```

On the perform method, I get the following error: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite.

From what I've read, this seems to mean that there are more than 1 element but I seem to have ruled this out with the number of buttons found.  I have attempted to do a wait to make sure it's available but I do not believe that is the issue.

I have tried to find an example just trying to do this with a Pinterest button because in theory it would be the same logic but I cannot find anything for that either.

My assumption is that it's a problem just getting the button to appear on the correct image?  But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly you want to click the button who appears in when you hoover the mouse in the image.

If you can hoover the mouse and wait until the expected xpath appears should solve it.

```
    protected virtual void HooverMouse(By element)
{
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(element)).Build().Perform();
}
```

The element will be the first image you have, so you must change your driver.findelements("the button") to the "images" and loop arround this.

In pseudo code will be:

Hoover(image) -> WaitButtonAppears -> ClickButton

Comment: So your code just does the hover of the image?  Then I do my code above to find and click the button?

Comment: So I modified the code to this:

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement image = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class, 'image_preview')]"));
actions.MoveToElement(image).Build().Perform();
IWebElement scheduleButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='tw_schedule_btn']"));
actions.MoveToElement(scheduleButton).Click().Perform();

But I still get the same error.

Comment: But if I get the problem correctly, there are more than one image, so you first get all  image elements with driver.FindElements and make a loop to first hoover the image and later click in the button who appears.
Also, have you tried to use native Selenium click instead actions click? And if there is a problem with native selenium Have you tried to make the click with JS? Like this code:
` IWebElement whereToClick = driver.FindElement(element);
            IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", whereToClick);`

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you mean by 'native selenium'.  I'm kind of new to selenium and I'm just trying to use what's available through the driver?  I have actually tried with the javascript executor and either it's not finding the element or it's not doing what it's supposed to because I don't get the pop-up window that should appear but I also don't get any console errors or other browser errors.

Comment: for native selenium im refering to driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("foo")).click() without any other action. 

It is possible that the hoover only not display the button or that there are some delay between the hoover and the button apereance. So you can try with some time between hoover and trying to find that particular element. 1 Sec should do the trick